# Multiple input formats with scanf

Tags: c, string, parsing, scanf

I'm looking to read in several data points from the user via `stdin` and `scanf()`.

However, if the user wishes to indicate invalid data, denoted by a `*`, this would violated the expected format (`%f`, `%d`, etc), and as I understand it, cause `scanf()` to return an error.

The way I conceived to deal with this is to read the input from `stdin` as a series of strings, check these for `*`, and then deal with that accodingly. This seems very naive and messy, and I was wondering if there was a cleaner way to accomplish this.

Please note, I am working in a very limited environment, so POSIX/3rd party solutions will not apply. ANSI C only :(

Comment: You need to read the input into a buffer and attempt to parse it repeatedly until you succeed. There is a lot of theory on doing this that is usually presented in  "compilers" course. If you don't want to go that route, you might use `fgets` or `getline` to read the input into a buffer and then process that a few time to see how it works, but it will get complicated and slow in a hurry unless there are only a limited number of possible correct parsings.

Comment: One word: `fgets()`. (OK, maybe two, `strchr()` applies as well.)

Comment: Don't use `scanf`. http://www.c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html

Comment: Was hoping for something elegant and simple, but it looks like @dmckee's response is the best way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general I recommend `fgets()` for input, but ...

There is a simple `scanf()` solution if you oblige the user to use "nan" for invalid data.  By entering "nan" (not-a-number), you solve 3 issues: this posted question, how to represent invalid data within your code and how to print out invalid data.

Example: Read 2 data points per line

```
#include<math.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
...
double f1, f2;
int i;
f1 = f2 = atof("NaN");
i = scanf("%lf %lf\n", &f1, &f2);
if (i != 2) {
  // Handle input error
}
if (isnan(f1)) { 
  // Handle invalid f1
}
...
```